# How to swap HTML image tags with Javascript using class selector of its parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I have the following lines of HTML code generated by a PHP plugin script, which I do not want to modify directly (for future upgrade compatibility purpose).

```
<div id="post-ratings-1981" class="post-ratings" data-nonce="0ab2fb33f4">

<img id="rating_1981_1" src="./rating_1_on.gif" alt="Down" title="Down" onmouseover="current_rating(1981, 1, 'Down');" onmouseout="ratings_off(2.5, 3, 0);" onclick="rate_post();" onkeypress="rate_post();" style="cursor: pointer; border: 0px;" />

<img id="rating_1981_2" src="./rating_2_on.gif" alt="Up" title="Up" onmouseover="current_rating(1981, 2, 'Up');" onmouseout="ratings_off(2.5, 3, 0);" onclick="rate_post();" onkeypress="rate_post();" style="cursor: pointer; border: 0px;" />

</div>
```

Basically it's outputting a thumbs-down and thumbs-up voting icon.

I would like swap the output position so it displays the thumbs-up icon first then thumbs-down, which makes more logical sense.

I find that if I can't directly modify the PHP script code controlling the output, and post-id is dynamically generated, is it possible to do it via Javascript Selector using the `class="post-ratings"`?

How can this be achieve via Javascript or jQuery?

PS: I might have multiple of the above `<div>` blocks with `class="post=ratings"` on a given listing page.

Comment: Put `position: relative` on the `div`, the `position: absolute` on the `img` elements. You can then swap their `left` positions as needed in CSS. However I'd strongly suggest the you do this in the PHP source though as you have access to it, and also look in to using unobtrusive JS event handlers instead of the ugly and outdated `on*` event attributes.

Comment: The `div` is hard coded in the php script, which I can't modify.

Comment: Then you can use the CSS method I mentioned. However I don't see why you can't modify the PHP if you have access to it.

Comment: Because it's a Wordpress plugin and gets update from time to time.  If it gets updated, all the custom modification will get overwritten.  I'm experimenting with `css` per your suggestion, and using `<img id="rating_1981_2" style="float:left">` in the Chrome Developer Tools seems doing the trick of swapping.  However, how can I create a `css` rule such that the second `img` element wrapped inside its parent `div` of class `post-ratings` is injected with `float:left;`?  If you can get this `css` write up as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it as a solution to my question.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes - that makes complete sense - I missed your first paragraph explaining it was a third party plugin. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use CSS. If you place `position: relative` on the parent `div` element, then `position: absolute` on the `img` elements you can position them wherever is required. Try this:

```js
// only here to stop console errors:
function ratings_off() {}
function current_rating() {}
```

```css
.post-ratings { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100px;
}
.post-ratings img { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
}
.post-ratings img:nth-child(1) { right: 0; }
.post-ratings img:nth-child(2) { left: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="post-ratings-1981" class="post-ratings" data-nonce="0ab2fb33f4">
  <img id="rating_1981_1" src="./rating_1_on.gif" alt="Down" title="Down" onmouseover="current_rating(1981, 1, 'Down');" onmouseout="ratings_off(2.5, 3, 0);" onclick="rate_post();" onkeypress="rate_post();" style="cursor: pointer; border: 0px;" />
  <img id="rating_1981_2" src="./rating_2_on.gif" alt="Up" title="Up" onmouseover="current_rating(1981, 2, 'Up');" onmouseout="ratings_off(2.5, 3, 0);" onclick="rate_post();" onkeypress="rate_post();" style="cursor: pointer; border: 0px;" />
</div>
```

You could use JS code to do this, however because of the delay in execution as the UI loads you would likely end up with a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Answer (score 1):

I do in this way using only jquery. I add for up img the css property float:left and for down img the property float:right. And then I append a span with css property clear:both to  clear past both left and right floats.

https://jsfiddle.net/byejkqg4/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".post-ratings").each(function(){
      $(this).find('img').eq(1).css('float','left');
      $(this).find('img').eq(0).css('float','right');
      $(this).find('img').eq(1).after('<span style="clear:both"></span>');
   })
})
```

Comment: as per your jsfiddle code, the result is not swapping the position, I'm still seeing the image in original order. Where `Up` is supposed to appear first, then `Down`